# MySQL Update: Unexpected input field parameter in database query

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

Whats wrong with this piece of code?

```
$SQL1 = "UPDATE table SET status='".$status."' WHERE email='".$client['email']."'";
```

I am getting error: Unexpected input field parameter in database query.

here is the full code

```
$server1 = "localhost";
$user_name1 = "DBUSER";
$passworda2 = "2HGfn5D480#";
$database2 = "DBNAME";
$db_handle1 = mysql_connect($server1, $user_name1, $passworda2);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database2, $db_handle1);
if ($db_found) {
$status = "6";

$SQL1 = "UPDATE table SET status=".$status." WHERE email='".$client['email']."'";

$result = mysql_query($SQL1);
mysql_close($db_handle1);
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle1);
}
```

Comment: include the schema of the table to the question

Comment: should i post all the table? the culomn type is int(11)

Comment: No just the result of `Describe tablename`

Comment: What data are you inserting? What is `$status` in this case?

Comment: i checked on diffrent database and other table and i get the same error

Comment: i am trying to change status from "1" to "6" $status = "6"; @JeroenJK

Comment: Can you remove the single quotes around `$status` and try it again? Since it has to be an integer it doesn't need the single quotes. So it will be this: `$SQL1 = "UPDATE table SET status=".$status." WHERE email='".$client['email']."'";`
Also, your method is very insecure. Anyone could do a SQL-injection on this.

Comment: i have removed the single ' around $status and its the same..what methoud do you recommend for better security? this code i am using in whmcs server module

Comment: Can you post your whole PHP-code that handles SQL?

Comment: use back tick instead of single quote mark?  ` vs ' for status`".$status."`  I always use back tick as it often saves me headache from typo errors in SQL syntax-ing

Comment: maybe your lacking another parameter here "$result = mysql_query($db_handle1,$SQL1);"

Comment: back tick didnt help, i am not sure if actually anything wrong with this code (perhaps not secured), but still don't understand why i get this error. on INSERT its working

Comment: @Aljie i have tried that as well...

Comment: and with this ? ""$result = mysql_query($db_found,$SQL1);"

Comment: same: Unexpected input field parameter in database query.

Answer (score 0):

seems the couse of the error was

```
mysql_close($db_handle1);
```

took me 4 hours to figure that out ! :D

Comment: Is it the part where it can't connect to the database and you're still trying to close it at "database not found"?