# MySQL - "Unexpected input field parameter in database query."

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code:

```
<?php

function widget_hello_world($vars) {

$username = "database_user";
$password = "database_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("database_name",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select database!");

$test1 = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE `Status`='new'");

mysql_close($dbhandle);

    $content = '<table class="table">
<thead><tr><th style="text-align:left;">Title</th><th style="text-align:left;">Data</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>

<tr><td>Test Data 1</td><td>{$test1}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test Data 2</td><td>{$test2}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test Data 3</td><td>{$test3}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>';

    return array( 'title' => 'Hellow World', 'content' => $content );

}

add_hook("AdminHomeWidgets",1,"widget_hello_world");

?>
```

This is the error message I'm getting when I go to the page:

```
Connected to MySQL
Unexpected input field parameter in database query.
```

Obviously it's connecting to the database, but it says there's an issue with the query.

At first I thought the issue was with this line:

```
$test1 = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) FROM Emails WHERE `Status`='new'");
```

However, even when I delete that line, the same error keeps on happening.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try testing a separate `die()` for the connection like : `<?php  
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypass');  
$selected_db = mysql_select_db('DB Name here');  
if (!$db_selected) {  
    die ('Database not selected : ' . mysql_error());  
}  
?> `

Comment: @Edper When I run that it does give the error `Database not selected :`

Comment: My variable is wrong by the way kindly change it to `if (!$selected_db)`. And if that's the case that it was not selected then try to find out if the spelling is correct for the selected db and then correct it.

Comment: Can you tell which line is raising the error?

Comment: @Username: `mysql_query` returns a `resource` (not a string) that you are assigning to $test1. How are you actually fetching the `count` value from $test1? Your code has no usage of `mysql_fetch_row`, `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_object`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this error occurs on mysql_close($dbhandle);

However, I also notice that reserved word "Table" should be back-tick to prevent an invalid query. Perhaps something in your callback routine is global and affecting the connection.

Also, use this:

echo mysql_error();

to see any mysql errors during query.

Comment: You forgot to add the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174435/mysql-update-unexpected-input-field-parameter-in-database-query) to the similar question. =)

Comment: Their solution was to remove that line it looks like and I tried that when reviewing that question before posting here.  When I remove that line, the error changes to this:  `Cannot apply currency format to 0. Unknown currency format details for currency type `

Comment: I just wanna to know that `mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");`  if connection become unsuccessful won't it throw die here ??

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. it will remove soon or later. please use `mysqli_` @Username

Comment: When I change the database password to something incorrect, it'll give the error `Unable to connect to MySQL`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a separate checking for the DB being selected, like:

```
 <?php $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypass'); 
    $selected_db = mysql_select_db('DB Name here'); 
    if (!$selected_db) 
       { 
         die ('Database not selected : ' . mysql_error()); 
       } 
 ?>
```

If it says 'Database is not selected' then check the spelling of your Database inside the `mysql_select_db()`. You could also comment the `mysql_close();` just to see if error will still persist.

On the other note it is better to use [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) because `mysql_` is deprecated or better yet use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).